# comments are displayed wrong when delete/edit button is removed due to authentication

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4, django-templates

My comment section is acting fine when am the user who typed the comments and have permission to see the edit delete button. Like in picture below:
[image: picture without delete/edit button gone]

But when I enter on a user who didn't post any of the comments and the delete and edit button dosen't show its a mess picture below:

[image: image without permission to see edit/delete button]

Its weird how do I fix it so the none owner of the comment that doesn't see the edit/delete button sees the field the same just excluded the delete/edit button?

**product_detail.html**

The code starts at the bottom of the template under:

Reviews

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block page_header %}
    <div class="container header-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 offset-lg-2">
                <div class="image-container my-5">
                    {% if product.image %}
                        <a href="{{ product.image.url }}" target="_blank">
                            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ product.image.url }}" alt="{{ product.name }}">
                        </a>
                        {% else %}
                        <a href="">
                            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}noimage.png" alt="{{ product.name }}">
                        </a>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <div class="product-details-container mb-5 mt-md-5">
                    <p class="mb-0">{{ product.name }}</p>
                    <p class="lead mb-0 text-left font-weight-bold">${{ product.price }}</p>
                    {% if product.category %}
                    <p class="small mt-1 mb-0">
                        <a class="text-muted" href="{% url 'products' %}?category={{ product.category.name }}">
                            <i class="fas fa-tag mr-1"></i>{{ product.category.friendly_name }}
                        </a>
                    </p>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if product.get_rating > 0 %}
                        <small class="text-muted"><i class="fas fa-star mr-1"></i>{{ product.get_rating }} / 5</small>
                    {% else %}
                        <small class="text-muted">No Rating</small>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
                        <small class="ml-3">
                            <a href="{% url 'edit_product' product.id %}">Edit</a> |
                            <a class="text-danger" href="{% url 'delete_product' product.id %}">Delete</a>
                        </small>
                    {% endif %}
                    <p class="mt-3">{{ product.description }}</p>
                    <form class="form" action="{% url 'add_to_bag' product.id %}" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="form-row">
                            {% with product.has_sizes as s %}
                            {% if s %}
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <p><strong>Size:</strong></p>
                                    <select class="form-control rounded-0 w-50" name="product_size" id='id_product_size'>
                                        <option value="xs">XS</option>
                                        <option value="s">S</option>
                                        <option value="m" selected>M</option>
                                        <option value="l">L</option>
                                        <option value="xl">XL</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            {% endif %}
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <p class="mt-3"><strong>Quantity:</strong></p>
                                <div class="form-group w-50">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                            <button class="decrement-qty btn btn-black rounded-0" 
                                                data-item_id="{{ product.id }}" id="decrement-qty_{{ product.id }}">
                                                <span class="icon">
                                                    <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
                                                </span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <input class="form-control qty_input" type="number"
                                            name="quantity" value="1" min="1" max="99"
                                            data-item_id="{{ product.id }}"
                                            id="id_qty_{{ product.id }}">
                                        <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <button class="increment-qty btn btn-black rounded-0"
                                                data-item_id="{{ product.id }}" id="increment-qty_{{ product.id }}">
                                                <span class="icon">
                                                    <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                                                </span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col{% if s %}-12 mt-2{% endif %}">
                                <a href="{% url 'products' %}" class="btn btn-outline-black rounded-0 mt-5">
                                    <span class="icon">
                                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="text-uppercase">Keep Shopping</span>
                                </a>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-black rounded-0 text-uppercase mt-5" value="Add to Bag">
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="redirect_url" value="{{ request.path }}">
                            {% endwith %}
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="w-full mt-6">
            <h2 class="text-xl">Reviews</h2>

            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                <form method="post" action="." class="mt-6 mb-6 p-6 bg-gray-100 rounded-xl">
                    {% csrf_token %}

                    <div>
                        <label>Rating</label><br>
                        <select class="form-control" name="rating">
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3" selected>3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="comment">Comment</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="content"></textarea>
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>

                </form>
            {% endif %}

            {% for review in reviews %}
            <div class="container">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jw55Ex/def_face.jpg" class="img img-rounded img-fluid" alt="Profile picture"/>
                                <p class="text-secondary text-center">{{ review.created_at|date:"Y-m-d" }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <p>
                                    <a class="float-left" style="color:blue"><strong>{{ review.created_by }}</a>
                                    <span class="float-right"><i class="text-warning fa fa-star">{{ review.rating }}/5</i></span>
                               </p>
                               <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <p>{{ review.content }}</p>
                                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                                {% if user.id == review.created_by.id %}
                                <p>
                                    <a class="float-right btn btn-primary ml-2 text-white"> <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</a>
                                    <a class="float-right btn text-white btn-danger"> <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</a>
                               </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            
                                </div>
                            </div>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block postloadjs %}
{{ block.super }}
{% include 'products/includes/quantity_input_script.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

`views.py:`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.db.models import Q
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

from .models import Product, Category, Review
from .forms import ProductForm

# Create your views here.

def all_products(request):
    """ A view to show all products, including sorting and search queries """

    products = Product.objects.all()
    query = None
    categories = None
    sort = None
    direction = None

    if request.GET:
        if 'sort' in request.GET:
            sortkey = request.GET['sort']
            sort = sortkey
            if sortkey == 'name':
                sortkey = 'lower_name'
                products = products.annotate(lower_name=Lower('name'))
            if sortkey == 'category':
                sortkey = 'category__name'
            if 'direction' in request.GET:
                direction = request.GET['direction']
                if direction == 'desc':
                    sortkey = f'-{sortkey}'
            products = products.order_by(sortkey)
            
        if 'category' in request.GET:
            categories = request.GET['category'].split(',')
            products = products.filter(category__name__in=categories)
            categories = Category.objects.filter(name__in=categories)

        if 'q' in request.GET:
            query = request.GET['q']
            if not query:
                messages.error(request, "You didn't enter any search criteria!")
                return redirect(reverse('products'))
            
            queries = Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(description__icontains=query)
            products = products.filter(queries)

    current_sorting = f'{sort}_{direction}'

    context = {
        'products': products,
        'search_term': query,
        'current_categories': categories,
        'current_sorting': current_sorting,
    }

    return render(request, 'products/products.html', context)


def product_detail(request, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        rating = request.POST.get('rating', 3)
        content = request.POST.get('content', '')
        Review.objects.create(
            product=product,
            rating=rating,
            content=content,
            created_by=request.user
        )
        # redirect to the same page
        return redirect('product_detail', product_id=product_id)

    reviews = Review.objects.filter(product=product)
    context = {
        'product': product,
        'reviews': reviews
    }
    return render(request, 'products/product_detail.html', context)


@login_required
def add_product(request):
    """ Add a product to the store """
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        messages.error(request, 'Sorry, only store owners can do that.')
        return redirect(reverse('home'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            product = form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Successfully added product!')
            return redirect(reverse('product_detail', args=[product.id]))
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Failed to add product. Please ensure the form is valid.')
    else:
        form = ProductForm()
        
    template = 'products/add_product.html'
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, template, context)


@login_required
def edit_product(request, product_id):
    """ Edit a product in the store """
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        messages.error(request, 'Sorry, only store owners can do that.')
        return redirect(reverse('home'))

    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=product)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Successfully updated product!')
            return redirect(reverse('product_detail', args=[product.id]))
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Failed to update product. Please ensure the form is valid.')
    else:
        form = ProductForm(instance=product)
        messages.info(request, f'You are editing {product.name}')

    template = 'products/edit_product.html'
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'product': product,
    }

    return render(request, template, context)


@login_required
def delete_product(request, product_id):
    """ Delete a product from the store """
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        messages.error(request, 'Sorry, only store owners can do that.')
        return redirect(reverse('home'))

    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    product.delete()
    messages.success(request, 'Product deleted!')
    return redirect(reverse('products'))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [edit and delete django comments not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72763767/edit-and-delete-django-comments-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem it was an error with autentication blocking the code making it not act as it should.

With the code below it looks normal even for none autenticated ppl in product_detail.html:

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <p>{{ review.content }}</p>
                                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                                {% if user.id == review.created_by.id %}
                                <p>
                                    <a a href="{% url 'edit_review' review.id %}" class="float-right btn btn-primary ml-2 text-white"> <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</a>
                                    <a href="{% url 'delete-review' review.id %}" class="float-right btn text-white btn-danger"> <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</a>
                               </p>
                                    {% endif %}
                               {% endif %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            
                                </div>
                            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```